# How to enable multiple Bluetooth LE notifications of a service on Android via Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I write my first Android app using Kotlin. This app scans and connects to my ble device. After I would like to stream some data via GATT notifications.

Currently I manage to enable the first notification, but struggle with any after. Maybe someone has an idea what went wrong.

A quick word on my own GATT service:

- it is a user defined one(UUID128)
- it has 5 characteristics

My characteristics:

- char1 - write
- char2 - read + notify
- char2 CCC
- char3 - read + notify
- char3 CCC
- char4 - read + notify
- char4 CCC
- char 5 write

I am using a nRF52840 dev board as device. On that dev board runs an own firmware(on Zephyr IOS). Via nRF connect I can enable notifications and read them. As well I done a Python script using bluepy that enables the notifications and successfully fetching the send data. Guess my GATT database setup is fine and as well the firmware handling the interaction. To enable the notifications from the firmware side the CCC field needs to be written.

Now I like to get these data on my Android phone. So I wrote an simple Android app. Everything goes fine, till I try to enable the notifications. I use:

```
for (d in gattChar.descriptors) {
            val `val` =
                if (enabled) BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE else BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
            d.value = `val`
            if (false == gatt.writeDescriptor(d)) {
                Log.e(LTAG,"writing descriptor ${d} failed")
            }
        }
```

Enabling the char2 goes well. But when I try to enable char3 and char4 fails after. Debugging BluetoothGatt.java file seems difficult. When steping into "writeDescriptor" it fails directly with "return false".
I maybe that the ble device is bussy(mDeviceBusyLock).

Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: Try to write descriptor one after another. Writing all may not succeed . You may use a delay

Comment: No, no delay please. What you must do is to wait for the corresponding callback after every GATT operation before you execute the next one. You are only allowed to have one outstanding GATT operation per BluetoothGatt object. In this case, wait for onDescriptorWrite before you can continue with the next write.

Comment: if I am setting a semaphore at the descriptor write callback and wait for it to be set, the code freezes. I have no idea of the ble implementation, but it seems that the processing of the write is done at the same thread. Any idea how to trigger write and wait for the completion?

Comment: @Emil how to do a "wait for onDescriptorWrite"?

Comment: I use this library in my android application: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library
The code to enable notifications is
enableNotifications(firstCharacteristic).enqueue();
enableNotifications(secondCharacteristic).enqueue();